# how do we add up arrarys of the same length at compile time

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

experts! I am thinking how to use template programing to finish element-wise array addition at compile time using C++17 or C++20. For example, 3 arrs {1,2,3}, {,2,4,6}, {3,6,9} would be added up to { 6, 12, 18 }. All elements at the same index on the given arrays would be added up. The following is my initial thougt.

```
template <int... I>
struct Seq {};

template < template<int...> typename...Seqs >
struct addSeq{};

int main(){

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<addSeq<Seq<1, 2, 3>,Seq<2, 4, 6>, Seq<3, 6, 9> >::type, Seq<6, 12, 18>>);

}
```

Any expert could provide some insigh?

the first problem I am running into is if I use such template interface for struct addSeq{}:

```
template < template<int...> typename...Seqs >
```

then I would have pass every int..T  for every Seqs to addSeq{}. I have no clue how to desgin struct addSeq such that I can only use it like

```
addSeq<Seq<1, 2, 3>,Seq<2, 4, 6>, Seq<3, 6, 9> >::type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use template partial specialization to do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int... I>
struct Seq {};

template <typename...Seqs >
struct addSeq { };

template <typename X, typename Y, typename... Rest>
struct addSeq<X, Y, Rest...> : addSeq<typename addSeq<X, Y>::type, Rest...> { };

template <int... Xs, int... Ys>
struct addSeq<Seq<Xs...>, Seq<Ys...>> {
  using type = Seq<(Xs + Ys)...>;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<addSeq<Seq<1, 2, 3>,Seq<2, 4, 6>, Seq<3, 6, 9> >::type, Seq<6, 12, 18>>);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, 康桓瑋. I am actually trying to generalize "template <int... I>struct Seq {};" into "template <typename... I>struct Seq {};" But then I can't compile. May I ask how we can get around it?

Comment: "*I am actually trying to generalize "template <int... I>struct Seq {};" into "template <typename... I>struct Seq {};"*" If so, how do you add up "types"?

Comment: I was aware of this. So I actually did one more thing, which is I added one more specializaion for Seq, "template <>struct<int...> Seq {};". Then compilation failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can still work with std::array at compile time since it is constexpr friendly (C++17 also). So the building block for working with arrays at compile time is still std::array. So I see no need to work through the extra complexity of template arguments for your values, and then the solution looks like this:

```
#include <array>

template<typename type_t, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
static constexpr auto sum_arrays(const std::array<std::array<type_t, M>, N>& arrays)
{
    std::array<type_t, M> sum{};

    for (const auto& array : arrays)
    {
        for (std::size_t index{}; index < M; ++index)
        {
            sum[index] += array[index];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> arrays
    {{
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9},
        {10,11,12}
    }};

    static constexpr auto sum = sum_arrays(arrays);

    static_assert(sum[0] == 22);
    static_assert(sum[1] == 26);
    static_assert(sum[2] == 30);

    return 0;
}
```

Note : do not forget to replace `static constexpr` with `inline constexpr` when moving the function to a header file.